# Can't access data in Context in MERN Stack Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

Why I can't access my product data from context?

Here is where product data came from:

```
const Products = props => {

    const [user, setUser, addToCart, setChosenImage] = useContext(UserContext);
    const [product, productData] = useContext(ProductContext);
    
    ...
    
    <div className="product--TopButton--Container">
        <button className="about--Button" onClick={() => productData(product._id)}>About</button>
    </div>
```

Here is the context:

```
export const ProductContext = React.createContext({})
const ProductProvider = ProductContext.Provider;

const ProductContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({})
    
    
    const productData = (id) => {
        fetch (`${API}/products/details/${id}`, {
            method: 'GET',
        })
        .then (response => response.json ())
        .then (response => {
            setProduct(response)
        })
        .then(() => window.location = `/details/${id}`)
        .catch (error => {
            console.error (error);
        })
    }
    
    console.log(product)
    return (
        <ProductProvider value={[product, productData]}>
            {props.children}
        </ProductProvider>
    )
}   

export default ProductContextProvider;
```

Note: The console.log is showing the correct product. But I can't access it in the ProductAbout component.

Here is how I provide it:

```
<ProductContextProvider>
    <Route exact path="/products" component={Products} />
    <Route exact path="/details/:id" component={ProductAbout} />
 </ProductContextProvider>
```

Here is where I'm trying to use it:

```
const ProductAbout = () => {

    const [product] = useContext(ProductContext)

    console.log(product)

    return(
        <div>hi{product?.name}</div>
    )
}

export default ProductAbout;
```

Comment: I think you should explain when you execute productData() ? and especially where your parameter (id) comes from ?

Comment: @Daphaz u can see the update on top

Comment: yes, but where does it come from? from which component?

Comment: Products component, when I click this about button I pass the ID to productData function and get the product by ID. Check the update

Comment: ok for me product._id doesn't exist yet since you do a setProduct(response) in productData() , product is for me an empty object

Comment: yes, and after I click the button and get the product the console.log(product) (in product context) is showing the whole product object, so it seams the function is providing the product correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232579/discussion-between-yollo-and-daphaz).